# How can I decode HTML entities?

Tags: html, perl, ascii, special-characters

Here's a quick Perl question:

How can I convert HTML special characters like `&uuml;` or `&#039;` to normal ASCII text?

I started with something like this:

```
s/\&#(\d+);/chr($1)/eg;
```

and could write it for all HTML characters, but some function like this probably already exists?

Note that I don't need a full HTML->Text converter. I already parse the HTML with the `HTML::Parser`. I just need to convert the text with the special chars I'm getting.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Take a look at [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Entities):

```
use HTML::Entities;

my $html = "Snoopy &amp; Charlie Brown";

print decode_entities($html), "\n";
```

You can guess the output.

Comment: For those who like the CLI one liners: `perl -MHTML::Entities -le 'print decode_entities("&iquest;&#39;")`

Comment: Great answer - this help me with my work!

Answer (score 23):

The above answers tell you how to decode the entities into Perl strings, but you also asked how to change those into *ASCII*.

Assuming that this is really what you want and you don't want all the unicode characters you can look at the [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/Text-Unidecode-0.04/lib/Text/Unidecode.pm) module from CPAN to Zap all those odd characters back into a roughly similar collection of ASCII characters:

```
use Text::Unidecode qw(unidecode);
use HTML::Entities qw(decode_entities);

my $source = '&#21271;&#20144;';  
print unidecode(decode_entities($source));

# That prints: Bei Jing
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that there are hex-specified characters too.  They look like this: &#xe9; (é).

Use HTML::Entities' decode_entities to translate the entities into actual characters.  To convert that to ASCII requires more work.  I've used iconv (perl interface: Text::Iconv)
with the transliterate option on with some success in the past.  But if you are dealing
with a limited set of entities, or you don't actually need it reduced to ASCII equivalents,
you may be better off limiting what decode_entities produces or providing it with custom
conversion maps.  See the HTML::Entities doc.

Answer (score 3):

There are a handful of predefined HTML entities - `&amp;` `&quot;` `&gt;` and so on - that you could hard code.

However, the larger case of numberic entities - `&#123;` - is going to be much harder, as those values are [Unicode](http://unicode.org/), and conversion to ASCII is going to range from *difficult* to *impossible*.

Comment: Quite right, Bevan. There's no such thing as a back-translation from Unicode to "plain ASCII". Joel wrote a really good article on text encodings, dehmann should read it...

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html 'All that stuff about "plain text = ascii = characters are 8 bits" is not only wrong, it's hopelessly wrong, and if you're still programming that way, you're not much better than a medical doctor who doesn't believe in germs.'

Comment: Perl: … making the hard things possible

Answer (score 0):

I use this script. Save it as `html2utf.py`, and use it ala `echo $some_html | html2utf.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
An alternative for `perl -Mopen=locale -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_ = decode_entities($_)'` (which you can use by `cpanm HTML::Entities`) and `recode html..`.
"""

import fileinput
import html

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(html.unescape(line.rstrip('\n')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a one-liner for bash, using Perl to decode the HTML entities that are passed to perl.  My solution is a blend of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576103/4220913) (see above) and something I found on [commandlinefu.com](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4840/url-encode) last week.

Most of us who code in Bash aren't in the habit of using `echo -n` to strip out the `\n` newline character since it doesn't usually affect Bash text parsing.  With Perl——and with this particular method——it's important to use `echo -n` or else perl will interpret the 'newline' `\n` character as a literal part of the response, adding an unwanted `%0A` to your results.

Here's my bash-perl one-liner hybrid:

```
encodedURL="$(echo -n "$entityURL" | perl -MHTML::Entities -MURI::Escape -ne 'print uri_escape(decode_entities($_))')"
```

Example:

Input: `Seals \&amp; Croft - Summer Breeze`

Output: `Seals%20%26%20Croft%20-%20Summer%20Breeze`