# Perl: parsing query_string containing backslash in cgi script

Tags: perl, cgi

I am a newbie here, I hope I am able to explain my issue properly...
 I have a html form that takes file name and location and cgi script processes this input.
file will be something like: file.ext and location will be like /some/folder/
My issue is, when i try to parse the querystring, the & and / in the string get converted to amp; and %2F and when i am trying to print the arguments, its not working...
here is the output:

```
testjarName=some.jar&loc=some%2Ffolder&host=r9_7079&action=PatchjarName
some.jar some.jar 
amp;loc
some some 
amp;host
r9_7079 r9_7079 
amp;action
Patch Patch 
FILE IS some.jar and LOCAITON IS
file is some.jar
location some
machine is r9_7079
action is Patch
You typed:
```

Can someone please help? i have tried the param() call too, but no help. Form input method is GET
Here is the script i am using:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
#print header;
#print start_html('A Simple Example'),
$my_input = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "";
print "<html><head></title>test</title></head><body>";
print "$ENV{QUERY_STRING}";
@fv_pairs = split /\&/ , $my_input;
foreach $pair (@fv_pairs) {
        if($pair=~m/([^=]+)=(.*)/) {
                $field = $1;
                print "$field";
                print "<br>";
                $value = $2;
                print "$value " ;
                $value =~ s/\+/ /g;
                print "$value " ;
                print "<br>";
                $value =~ s/%([\dA-Fa-f]{2})/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
                $INPUT{$field}=$value;
        }
}
print "<br><hr>"; print "FILE IS  $INPUT{jarName} and LOCAITON IS  $INPUT{loc}";
if (param()) {
print "<hr>";
    print
        "file is ",em(param('jarName')),
        p,
        "location ",em(join(", ",param('loc'))),
        p,
        "machine is  ",em(param('host')),
        p,
        "action is ",em(param('action')),
        hr;
print "You typed: " . $input{'loc'} . "\n";


}

print "</body></html>";
#print end_html;
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML::Entities to encode / decode input strings.
([How can I decode HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576095/how-can-i-decode-html-entities))

Answer (score 0):

[`param`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-THE-VALUE-OR-VALUES-OF-A-SINGLE-NAMED-PARAMETER%3a) will break up the query string and decode HTML characters for you:

```
perl -e 'use CGI qw(:standard);
         print param("loc");
' 'testjarName=some.jar&loc=some%2Ffolder&host=r9_7079&action=PatchjarName'
```

Output:

```
some/folder
```